# React-Router Race Condition

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to implement protected routes. The issue is, the navigate happens before the `setSession` has updated meaning the `authContext` is still false and the protected route component sends the user back to `/sign-in`

This is the `handleSubmit` function on my sign in form

```
    const handleSubmit =
      async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let { data, error } = 
          await auth.signIn({
            email,
            password
          })

        if (error)
          setAuthError(error.message);

        if (data)
          navigate('/dashboard');
      }
```

This is the `signIn` function on my context, called by the function above

```
async ({ email, password }) => {
        let { data, error } =
          await client.auth.signInWithPassword({
            email,
            password
          })

        if (data)
          setSession(data.user)

        return { data, error }
      },
```

...and of course the protected route component is essentially

```
let { isSignedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    return (
      isSignedIn
        ? children
        : <Navigate to="/sign-in" replace />
    )
```

From looking around this seems to be the basic structure that protected route tutorials have: use a handler function to call the sign-in function on a context; context sets some state and returns; the handler function then navigates.

I'm using React-Router 6.8.0. Funnily enough, the sign-in/out button in the nav (which is not under the react router `<Outlet/>` seems to work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a separate state for managing when the checking of the auth status is happening.  At the the minute your logic doesn't cover that scenario, for example, something like -

```
let { isSignedIn, isAuthLoading } = useContext(AuthContext);

   if(isAuthLoading) return <Loading />
    
    return (
      isSignedIn
        ? children
        : <Navigate to="/sign-in" replace />
    )
```

or whatever way you feel best suits your app structure, but essentially, you need to have some way of handling the states that represent when you're either checking if the user is authenticated, or during authentication, *then* you can use your existing private route logic when you *know* if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Hrm, I don't have that information though. The API I'm using gives me a promise with data and error on it.

Comment: yes, so when the API request is in flight, i.e. the promise has not yet been fulfilled, then thats when its loading, right? You just have to maintain that state yourself separately.  But from what I gather from your question, you have at least 3 states to handle for the user - 1) when you don't yet if they're logged in or not, or when its currently trying to sign them in, 2) When then are logged in and 3) When they are not logged in.  At the minute you are trying to handle those 3 scenarios with a single boolean (isSignedIn), which isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I described the issue very well. The promise had been fulfilled (I awaited the API call) so it wasn't a case of modelling the pending states. The issue was the `signIn` function on the context setting state AND returning data for the `handleSubmit` function to use. It was this divergence which was causing the "race" condition.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this is due to "batching" - [https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21.), the fix was to use `flushSync` around the `setSession` state call.

React applies the `setSession` call asynchronously, and in this case the state still hasn't been updated by the time the `<ProtectedRoute/>` component is hit (after we've navigated with `navigate('/dashboard')`), so `isSignedIn` is still false so we get sent back to `/sign-in`.

I'm guessing the majority of those "protected routes" tutorials are using React < 18, where there was no batching of `setState` calls outside of event handlers i.e inside promises which means they updated synchronously and thus the above pattern worked without the use of `flushSync`.